# Get Current Country Code Magento 1

Tags: shipping, magento-1.4, country-regions

I am trying to get  Current Country Code Magento 1

using below code

```
$currentCountry = GeoIP_Core::getInstance(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "geoip" . DS . "GeoLiteCity.dat", GeoIP_Core::GEOIP_STANDARD)
            ->geoip_country_code_by_addr(Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr());
    }
```

But its not giving me proper country code,

Is their any way to get it ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
$ipAddress =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$json       = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ipAddress}/json");
$details    = json_decode($json);
if(isset($details->country)) {
    echo $details->country;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This does not work, i have tried here - https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_echo1

Comment: it working for me.you add this script in your server then after check.

Comment: Thanks does it return Two digit country code ?

Comment: Yes.
"country": "IN",

Comment: Thanks Jigar, i will check it soon on server.

Comment: ok.@Hamendra Sunthwal